# Variable in Params Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I put a variable `i` in the param name?

```
for i in 1..4
  if !params[:option#{i}].empty?
    @option#{i} = true
  end
end
```

Trying to produce: `if !params[:option1].empty?` and `@option1 = true`

I tried using `{{i}}` `\i` `#{i}`

#### Update:

As @Cary pointed out, it would also be useful to see:

```
params = { :option1=>[], :option2=>[2,3], 'cat'=>'9lives', :option3=>[4] }
```

Comment: What about `!params["option#{i}".to_sym].empty?`

Comment: @Abhi: No need to use `.to_sym` if it's controller params. It'll happily accept strings too

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ya that's correct. Thanks !!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for i in 1..4
  if !params["option#{i}".to_sym].empty?
    instance_variable_set("@option#{i}", true)
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. how about something like this `@option#{i} = true` for `@option1 = true`?

Comment: You can do something like this: `instance_variable_set("@option#{i}", true)`. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Consider adding the example: `params = { :option1=>[], :option2=>[2,3], 'cat'=>'9lives', :option3=>[4] }` and expressing your answer:  `(1..3).each { |i| instance_variable_set("@option#{i}", true) if params["option#{i}".to_sym].any? }; @option1.nil? #=>true; @option2 #=>true; @option3 #=> true`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
!params["option#{i}".to_sym].empty?
```

This will first replace the value of **i** inside the string and then convert the entire string into symbol (using `to_sym`)

**Complete Code**

```
for i in 1..4
  if !params["option#{i}".to_sym].empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: Added an edit. Should I do the same for `@option#{i} = true` to `@option1 = true`?

Comment: @Onichan You can try `instance_variable_set` as suggested by **Zoran**. And in case you want to compare the value, try `instance_variable_get("@option#{i}") == true`